# Upgrading Azure FunctionApps from .NET 6 to .NET 8: no need to serialize object data from eventGridEvent?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-8.0

(to refresh your memory) The usual set up for an Azure Function app is:

```
[Function("ExampleFunctionApp")]
public async Task RunAsync([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log = null)
{
    // .... your code
}
```

In .NET 6, we used to deserialize object data from an eventGridEvent using something like this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventGridEventModel>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventGridEvent.Data));
```

Now to get this working in .NET 8, I had to convert the above code to:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventGridEventModel>(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
```

I was wondering if there was some sort of update to a library that facilitated this? Or if anyone has any insights into why this is happening, it would be greatly appreciated!